# What is it that perks require?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

While selecting perks for my first two levels I've noticed that plenty of them state that they "Require: 30", for example, but didn't really have long enough last night to play around and find out *what* the perk required 30 of.

So what is it that perks require a certain value of?
Level in that skill?
Character level?
Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's points in that skill.

For example, to get Expert Illusion you need 75 Illusion.

Comment: Lovely, I'd assumed as much but it's nice to know for sure in advance.

Comment: Also note that in order to get more advanced perks, you need to first get the other ones in the "path."